# What are more formal words/phrases for "pass sth on to sb" and "get back to someone"?

Tags: expressions, phrasal-verbs, formal-language, informal-language

In the following sentence, I feel that the phrases "pass on to" and "get back to" are rather informal. Am I right about this, and, if so, what are more formal expressions I could use?

> The board will **pass** the matter **on to** the council for deliberation, and once the council has discussed the matter, they will **get back to** the board with their recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common formal equivalent would be:

- The board will **forward** the matter <s>on</s> to the council for deliberation.

There is no need to use "on" with this verb because that is implied.

You might also want to use 'consideration' instead of 'deliberation'.

You could also use the word 'escalate', but only if the party that the matter is being forwarded to is considered to be a higher tier of some structure, for example, "*it was escalated to management for consideration*". You could also use the word 'submit' but that is not only a formal word but sounds like a formal *process*, so it may or may not be appropriate.

---

In turn, the common formal equivalent for responding would be:

- they will **respond** to the board with their recommendations.

You could perhaps also consider '*reply*', or maybe '*return*'.

Answer (score 1):

These expressions are not informal.

I suppose you could use "The board will send the matter to the council" or "Will submit the matter to the council"

And the "council will inform the board of its recommendations"

Comment: Oh, ok – so you'd say "pass on" and "get back to"  could be used in a rather formal, official document?

Comment: There are degrees of formality. Using everyday language is quite commonplace in business these days, but 'pass on' and 'get back' are a bit casual. If I left an important message with someone and they said they'd "pass it on", I'd be left with nagging doubts that they understood the importance of it. It sounds like it will be written on a scrap of paper and left on someone's desk to be missed. More formal words inspire confidence.

Comment: I'd be happy to use expressions in normal communications: business emails, weekly bulletins etc. There may be some contexts in which a heightened level of formality is needed, and "submit" is a nice formal term.